# typedef struct error in c program

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Thanks for sharing your knowladge:)!
I just wrote this c program in devc++ and I've got alot of errors about the typdef and the struct
like: "invalid use of undefined type `struct item'" for every line with "->" operator, "forward declaration of`struct item'" for line 4
this  is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item* ptr;
typedef struct itme
{
        int data;
        ptr next;
}node;
void add2list(ptr*,int);
void freeList(ptr*);
int main()
{
    ptr H=NULL;
    ptr p3=H;
    int num;
    while (scanf("%d",&num)!=EOF)
          add2list(&H,num);

    while(p3)
    {
            printf("%d  ",p3->data);
            p3=p3->next;
    }
    printf("end\n");   
    freeList(&H);
    return 0;
}

void add2list(ptr* H, int num)
{
     ptr p1,p2,T;
     T=(ptr)malloc(sizeof(node));
     if(!T)
     {
           printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
           exit(0);
     }
     t->data=num;
     p1=*H;
     while(p1)
     {
           if(p1->data==num)
           {
              free(T);
              goto duplicate;
           }   
           else 
           {
                p2=p1;
                p1=p1->next;
           }
     }
     T->next=p1;
     if(p1==*H)
         *H=T; 
     else
     p2->next=T;
     duplicate:;
}   
void freeList(ptr* H)
{
     ptr p1;
     while(H)
     {
         p1=*H;
         (*H)=p1->next;
         free(p1);
     }

}
```

thanks!

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc` in C, and why do you need `ptr` and `node` (you don't use `node`), but also `ptr` is declared before `item`?

Comment: `typedef struct itme{` check the typo here. also, move `typedef struct item* ptr;` after the structure definition. why do you need both `H` and `p3`?

Comment: @dvir naim Do not listen low-qualified programmers and in most cases place casting before malloc in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not looked all your code but it seems there is a typo

typedef struct **item*** ptr;

typedef struct **itme**
{

Also this code snippet

```
while(p3)
{
        printf("%d  ",p3->data);
        p3=p3->next;
}
```

has no sense because `p3` was explicitly initialized by NULL

```
ptr H=NULL;
ptr p3=H;
```

At least before the loop you should add statement

```
p3 = H;
```

Also in function `add2list` there is another typo

You declared pointer `T` but then further are using pointer `t`

```
void add2list(ptr* H, int num)
{
     ptr p1,p2,T;
     T=(ptr)malloc(sizeof(node));
     if(!T)
     {
           printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
           exit(0);
     }
     t->data=num;
```

Function freeList is also wrong.

Instead of statement

```
 while(H)
```

there shall be

```
 while( *H )
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you spelled "item" "itme".  Happens to the best of us.

Comment: @dvir naim You are wrong. It does not solve your problem because there are other typos and errors. See my answer.